# PHP sorting 5 numbers per row

Tags: php

Hi I have made script that shows only even numbers and now i have to do that shows only 5 even numbers per row example:
numbers must be sorted like this

`2,4,6,8,10`

`12,14,16,18,20`

i must have numbers written like that current code that i am using for showing only even numbers is under. but if someone can help me how can i show only 5 per row i will be thankful. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
  $p=100;
  for($p=100;$p>=0;)
  { 
    echo "$p,";
    $p=$p-2;
  }
?>
```

Comment: `$p%10 == 0` in your for loop

Comment: @user3222689 did you check my answer and not found it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?PHP 
$p=100;
$count=0;
for($p=100;$p>=0;)
{   
  echo "$p";
  $p=$p-2;
$count+=1;
if($count==5){
$count=0;
echo "<br/>";
}
else echo " ,";
}
?>
```

Comment: you should be using == or === in conditional statements

Comment: @thescientist Thank you for pointing that out! Always miss that :) +1 to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) i have accepted your anwser you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
echo implode("\n",array_map(function($a) {return implode(",",$a);},array_chunk(range(0,100,2),5)));
```

Result:

> 0,2,4,6,8
>   10,12,14,16,18
>   20,22,24,26,28
>   30,32,34,36,38
>   40,42,44,46,48
>   50,52,54,56,58
>   60,62,64,66,68
>   70,72,74,76,78
>   80,82,84,86,88
>   90,92,94,96,98
>   100

Function reference: [`implode`](http://php.net/implode), [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map), [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array-chunk), [`range`](http://php.net/range).

For rendering in a browser, replace `\n` with `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
<?php for($p=100;$p>=0;$p-2){
          echo "$p";
          if($p%5==0){ 
              echo "<br>";
          }
          else { 
              echo ", "; 
          }
      }
?>
```

Comment: This will not work when seeding is not from 100 say it starts from 98.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi ya you are right..!!ur answer will work for it.. i thought in the same way in the begining.. but for the given scenario... this may be efficient..